# Подсветка многострочного текста в двойных и одинарных кавычках

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt

Использую класс из документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html

для подсвечивания кода в `textEdit` так:

```
highlighter = new Highlighter(textEdit->document());
```

Но как сделать так, чтобы подсвечивал многострочный текст в одинарных и двойных кавычках?

Comment: на этой же странице есть пример - `rule.pattern = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("\".*\""));` Подходит?

Comment: нет, он только на одной строке подсвечивает

Comment: я не уверен, что для строк это будет работать, но там есть пример, как сделать многострочный комментарий. Может его использовать как многострочную строку?

Comment: пытался так: commentStartExpression = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("\""));

Comment: commentEndExpression = QRegularExpression(QStringLiteral("\""));